# Está dando erro no (valorG) dentro do meu IF em todos os parênteses ali do IF o que pode ser?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
package com.example.testetrabalho;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //variaveis
    EditText editTextValorG;
    EditText editTextValorL;
    EditText editTextValorP;
    Button btnCalcula;
    private EditText textViewMostra;
    private TextView textViewtMostra;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextValorG = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValorG);
        editTextValorL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValorL);
        editTextValorP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValorP);
      //  textViewMostra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMostra);
        btnCalcula = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalcula);


        //funçao do botao calcular

        btnCalcula.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double valorG = Double.parseDouble(editTextValorL.getText().toString());
                double valorL = Double.parseDouble(editTextValorL.getText().toString());
                double valorP = Double.parseDouble(editTextValorP.getText().toString());


                //IF

                if ((valorG < valorL) && (valorG < valorP))
                    textViewMostra.setText(valorG);

                else if ((valorL < valorG) && (valorL < valorP))
                    textViewMostra.setText(valorL);

                else if ((valorP < valorG) && (valorP < valorL))
                    textViewMostra.setText(valorP);


            }


        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Ajudaria se publicasse junto da questão as mensagens de erro e valor do stack trace. Mas olhando por cima tenta isso aqui `textViewMostra.setText(String.valueOf(valorG));` ou então na linha `double valorG = Double.parseDouble(editTextValorL.getText().toString());` mude para `String valorG = editTextValorL.getText();` e faça o mesmo para `valorL` e `valorP`. Também da para questionar a necessidade das variáveis  `valorG`, `valorL` e `valorP` em seu código, pois pode fazer 'textViewMostra.setText(editTextValorL.getText());' e o mesmo com `valorL` e `valorP`.

Comment: Vou ajustar.obrigada

Comment: O erro que dá seria li nas variaveis entre() do if fica os tracinhos vermelho abaixo e diz Cannot resolve method 'setText(double)'

Comment: Esse erro esta dando pois o setText não aceita um double, veja aqui os tipos aceitos https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText